# Embedding Online Modern Sharepoint Form controls in custom .aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form, list-form, aspx

I'm wondering if it is possible to embed or call to field type like "person or group" to work in another .aspx page. I'm creating a form and the default modern form's layout even with the new JSON layout isn't good enough. I have also looked into Power Apps. The issue with Power Apps is that it will not display a multi-line text field with word wrap or auto expand to fully display the text. I was hoping to use the form controls on custom .aspx pages for improved formatting. Can this be done? If so, where can I find out how? Thanks

Comment: Can you illustrate more ? I think Power Apps can serve you on that

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Power Apps can make a multi-line text field that can grow  when filled with text? This is not a mobile app and it might extend further then a normal canvas app. In this Form I would need 14 multi line text fields that would open to always display the full text. Also, tighter formatting then cards allow..